# One Docstring for multiple Functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I have two functions

```
function foo() end
function bar() end
```

Is it possible as in R for example to write a single docstring for both functions?

Comment: One thing to consider is that if you have two things that can share docs, they might want to be two methods of the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**
Place docstrings directly before or above defined name (s) separate by a comma.

```
function foo() end
function bar() end

"baz" foo, bar

"baz"
foo, bar

"""
baz
"""
foo, bar
```

**Method 2**. Multiple functions can be defined and documented directly.

```
"baz"
function foo() end, # note the comma
function bar() end
```

**Method 3**
Refer to docs by macro.

```
"baz"
function foo() end
function bar() end
@doc (@doc foo) bar
```

---

**Further reading**

- [Guide & Julia conventions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/documentation/#Functions-and-Methods)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a string with the common docstring and interpolate it into the docstrings of your functions, e.g.

```
julia> docstr = "hello world!"
"hello world!"
julia> "$docstr"
       function foo() end
foo

help?> foo
search: foo floor pointer_from_objref OverflowError RoundFromZero unsafe_copyto! functionloc StackOverflowError

  hello world!

julia> "$docstr"
       function bar() end
bar

help?> bar
search: bar baremodule SubArray GlobalRef clipboard BitArray backtrace BitMatrix catch_backtrace AbstractRange

  hello world!
```